# extra trailing slash mod-rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I got a problem of the extra trailing slash that directs my website from

http://www.example.com/index to http://www.example.com//index

here's my .htaccess content

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    # Apply rule to all web pages eg html, php, htm
    # RewriteRule !\.(swf|zip|tar|tar|pdf|doc|txt|js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|php)$ index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule captcha.jpg com/actions/image.php
    RewriteRule !(\.) index.php [NC,L]


#deny access to the .ht* files

  order allow,deny
  deny from all


#deny access to any *.ini files

  order allow,deny
  deny from all


#deny access to any *.log files

  order allow,deny
  deny from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the

```
RewriteBase /
```

By default, a .htaccess file in a directory will have a base path of / , so by adding another forward slash your overall rewrite base will be  //